# Python: if abc in j['category']

Tags: python, json, list, python-2.7

Given a JSON file that looks like this:

```
"foobar": [
    {
        "a": "true",
        "b": 1,
        "c": 1234,
        "d": 9,
        "e": "red"
    },
    {
        "a": "false",
        "b": 2,
        "c": 2345,
        "d": 7,
        "e": "green"
    },
    {
        "a": "whocares",
        "b": 3,
        "c": 3456,
        "d": 5,
        "e": "blue"
    }
]
```

Is is possible to check if "blue" is present in **any** of these, without a loop?

```
import simplejson
j = json.loads(superfile().text)
if "blue" in j['foobar'][ANYONE]['e']
```

Comment: why are you trying to avoid a loop? is the list too big?

Comment: ...[`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)?

Comment: @RafaelBarros Not necessarily. I am just trying to keep things simple.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You may want to provide an example with that. `any` usually simply checks if a list element is true. In this case, the list elements are dicts, and the question is to find out, for each dict element, if one of the dict values is "blue".

Comment: @Evert Cyber has kindly done so for me!

Comment: Just noticed when I hit enter on my previous comment ;-).

Comment: You could get the text from the file as a string, then you would simply do:

    `if "blue" in text_string:`

But with this approach you won't be able to access your json object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) mentioned, your best bet is probably to use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), for example

```
if any('blue' in i['e'] for i in j['foobar'])
```

Or

```
if any('blue' == i['e'] for i in j['foobar'])
```

Comment: When `blue` is a variable, this also catches "bl". Can this be avoided?